# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre la flecha -> y => en PHP?

Tags: php

Me gustaría saber para qué sirven estas flechas

```
-> o =>
```

¿Son lo mismo? ¿para qué sirven y qué diferencia tienen?

En este ejemplo no sé qué diferencia hay y para qué sirven estas flechas. ¿Alguien me indica? `=>` y `->`

```
$this->gid = $gid;
$this->link = $link;
$this->sql = "SELECT [g].[GuildName], [g].[Country], [g].[TotalCount], [g].[GuildPoint], [g].[CreateDate], [gd].[Remark], [c].[CharName] FROM [PS_GameData].[dbo].[Guilds] AS [g]
              INNER JOIN [PS_GameData].[dbo].[GuildDetails] AS [gd] ON [gd].[GuildID] = [g].[GuildID]
              INNER JOIN [PS_GameData].[dbo].[Chars] AS [c] ON [c].[CharID] = [g].[MasterCharID]
              WHERE [g].[GuildID] = '$gid'
              ORDER BY [g].[GuildPoint] DESC, [g].[GuildName] ASC";
$this->res = odbc_exec($this->link, $this->sql);
$this->fet = odbc_fetch_array($this->res);
$this->GuildName        = $this->fet['GuildName'];
$this->Country          = $this->fet['Country'];
$this->Member           = $this->fet['TotalCount'];
$this->GuildPoint       = $this->fet['GuildPoint'];
$this->CreateDate       = $this->fet['CreateDate'];
$this->Remark           = $this->fet['Remark'];
$this->LeaderCharName   = $this->fet['CharName'];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`->` es el utilizado para referirse a un método u objeto dentro de un objeto.

```
$objeto = new MiClase();
$objeto->x = 5; //Se usa -> para "usar" la variable del objeto
$objeto->miMetodo();//Lo mismo para usar el método
```

`=>` se utiliza como asignación de valores para un array. Por ejemplo:

```
$miArray = array(
   'clave' => 'valor'
);
```

Answer (score 3):

El elemento `->` se utiliza para hacer referencia a un objeto.

```
$result = $db->query($consulta);
```

El Operador `=>` se utiliza como asignación de valores para un array.

```
array(
    clave  => valor1,
    clave2 => valor2
    )
```

Hasta donde sé, no existe el operador `-->`